# Column level access in Apache Sentry

Tags: apache, hive, apache-sentry

How can I put column level access in a hive table through Apache Sentry?

Comment: "Could someone help me understand how to..." the only possible answers are  "Yes" or "No". How would that help you? Always ask questions in a way that the answer directly helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Column Level Security is added in CDH 5.5. Pls refer to http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_hive_sql.html?scroll=concept_c2q_4qx_p4__col_level_auth_sentry#concept_c2q_4qx_p4__col_level_auth_sentry

You can grant and revoke specific columns that a user has access to from the table.

Answer (score -1):

```
create database XXX;

create view XXX.ABC as select X, Y, Z from XXX.ABC;
```